# Allow "trusted users" to see deleted users contributions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users, trusted-user

Could we allow for "Trusted Users" (>= 20K rep) to be able to see **deleted** users contributions to the Stack Exchange?

They can already see deleted questions and answers, why not a deleted contributions?

---

So for example I would be able to see all of the contributions that were made by the user who gave me this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5875043/561731) to my question.

Searching for `user:1385191` does not work at all...

Comment: Isn't deleting a user a hard-delete? The way their posts get anonymized makes me suspect that.

Comment: @Neal, why would we need to?

Comment: @CodesInChaos not at all.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi see my update. I want to see all the answers and question that a deleted user contributed to SO.

Comment: It's pretty close to a hard delete. Mods don't get to see deleted user accounts either; which is sort of unfortunate for when a deleted user comes back with more spam/etc. We just get a 404 page. I too would like a list of their answers/questions

Comment: @Neal, ah, fair enough :) IIRC though, *some* users actually want all their posts to be disassociated from their account when they ragequit^W find more interesting things to do. Your proposal would go against this kind of request.

Comment: @AnnaLear -- care to comment?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Geez, give me  a second or thirty. :P

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Deleted accounts aren't always ragequits.

Comment: @AnnaLear naaah :-P not allowed ^_^

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi We can do that too, though it's a bit different from account deletion. Deleting your account isn't the only way to disassociate yourself from your posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this unusual case, where you know the user's old ID, you can take advantage of Google's constant indexing of SO. Search for

> site:stackoverflow.com user1385191

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=strict&output=search&q=site:stackoverflow.com+user1385191&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+user1385191

Comment: I'm satisfied with this answer because it does technically allow you to "see all of the contributions" the user made. You wanted them sorted? Good luck with that.

Answer (score 14):

Nobody can see deleted accounts - not even developers. Deleted accounts are fully deleted. There's nothing to see basically by definition.

Comment: So how can I search for contributions by the afformentioned deleted user? Searching `user:1385191` yields nothing....

Comment: Um... You can't? :D

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA You cannot. And you're not supposed to. When an account is deleted, it is disassociated from all existing posts *by design*.

Comment: @AnnaLear yes but their user ID gets put there in it's stead. shouldn't that count for something?

Comment: The CC:Wiki license specifies that a user may ask that his account be disassociated from his posts, which is essentially what an account deletion is. That doesn't mean sorta disassociated, or kinda disassociated, it means *disassociated.* Which basically amounts to deletion. Not the kind of soft deletion where you put a delete flag on the record, but real, actual deletion. SE might even scrub the hard drives with a Brillo pad, just to be sure.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA No, it shouldn't. There is no active user with that ID, so you cannot search by it. The whole point of deleting an account is to make it inaccessible, unreferenced, and unlinked. We're not going to implement "soft" account deletion.

Comment: @Robert, ah, so when you receive a request for disassociation, you actually *delete* the account? There is no middle ground?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I don't have the ability to disassociate individual posts, but the devs and the community team do.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Nah, they pass the request to us and we push a button to remove account association from the specific post.